# Shift selecting in the Outliner

Tags: baking

When <kbd>⇧Shift</kbd> selecting objects in the 3D viewport the **last** selected object is, as expected, the Active Object.

[image]

But in the Outliner, <kbd>⇧Shift</kbd> selecting the objects in the same order makes the first object the Active object.

[image]

In the Outliner, it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> select to make the last selected object the active object.

[image]

Is there a reason for this difference? I just find it a bit confusing when selecting objects in the Outliner for baking high to low poly.

Comment: Only the devs can say that for sure, but my take on it is that Shift select in the outliner is used for "fill selection" (as in pick one object, pick another a few lines down and all objects in between get selected as well), so you don't have to pick one by one. Since it has the potential to select any arbitrary number of objects at a time, it is not clear which one should be active, setting one could lead to unexpected results. Ctrl selection on the other hand only picks objects you explicitly click on, so it can set them as active without unforeseen side effects.

Comment: TY Duarte, I only asked because I had spent a frustrating hour trying to do a high to low normal bake only to realise that I had mistakenly been using SHFT select instead of CTRL select in the Outliner.

Comment: Check the keymaps, it might be configurable behavior